# Can I host the code on TFS cloud and build locally

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I want to use existing TFS build scripts but move my code to the TFS cloud.
Can this be done?

Is it as simple as changing the "Source Control Folder" in the Build Definition? (I doubt it).

We have a local build machine which I want to use as it has custom installations required for the build to succeed.

Comment: Could this be my answer, Yes, http://myalmblog.com/2014/04/configuring-on-premises-build-server-for-visual-studio-online/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. If you install and configure a TF Build Controller locally you can connect it to VSO. Add some agents and you can build hapily locally with all you code safe and secure in the cloud.